# Pass an object's method to a function in Javascript. Is this the correct interpretation of the question?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, arguments, this

I was in an interview, and there was this question:

> When the method X of an object O is passed to a function Y as a parameter, what happens if X contains a reference to 'this' and gets executed inside Y? Please provide code examples.

Is this code a correct interpretation of the question?

```
let O = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
  X() {
    console.log(this.name);
  },
};
let generic = O.X();

function Y(param) {
  return param;
}
console.log(Y(generic));
```

Could you please help me understand and reply to the question, even if just with an example?

Comment: *"... and gets executed inside Y?"* So the questioner doesn't really understand JavaScript, then, since it doesn't matter **where** it's executed, it matters **how**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks if the *function* is passed, not if the function is invoked immediately, then passed. They were probably thinking of something like this:

```js
let O = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
  X() {
    console.log(this.name);
  },
};
function callbackInvoker(fn) {
  fn();
}
callbackInvoker(O.X);
```

As you can see, unless the passed method is bound first, or is an arrow function, its `this` binding to the `O` object will have been lost, which is probably what the question was intending to test you about.

Answer (score 0):

```
let O = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
  X() {
    console.log(this.name);
  },
};
let generic = O.X;

function Y(fn) {
  return fn(); // <-- execute here
}
console.log(Y(generic));
```